# how to create UI to get the users birthday in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

what I am creating is a sign in form for my app. And I want to get the users birthday in to my app.

Problem is that how do I put the text fields to get the users birthday (like 07/08/2020)

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: You can use Masked Text Field